# Using unevenly bent bars at the gym for squats (general tips and comfort)

Tags: squats, barbell

At the gym I go to, it seems so all bars got bent as a result of people deadlifting. They have bought no rubber plate nor the platform hence the problem is quite exacerbated. The main problem I have is, the bars are bent unevenly about the center.

I'm trying to make the best of this situation, hence I have two questions:

1. Would it be better to use high bar / low bar technique when squatting with bent bars?
2. Would using foam padding to offset the bentness be a good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Deadlifting doesn’t bend bars. They’re most likely bent from being dropped onto racks or benches under load (hence the uneven bend). Don’t blame the deadlifters.

Comment: Also, your question needs to specify what your goal here is. Better for *what*, exactly?

Comment: Like are you looking for better comfort? Reduced risk of injury? Exercises efficiency? General tips on how to position the bar to not be uneven?

Comment: @SeanDuggan general tips with direction to comfort

Comment: This is outside of my realm of experience, but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UJTELgs1TA might be handy.

Comment: Those are evenly bent bars @SeanDuggan

Answer (score 1):

Poking around, the general advice I've run into is to [not use unevenly bent bars](https://www.fitnessbaddies.com/bent-barbells/).

> Let me start by saying that if your barbell is bent unevenly or past the point of saving, you need to replace it. It’s no longer safe to use it.

If your gym doesn't care enough to provide safe equipment, you may want to avoid that gym. Or do other exercises.